# Query values from two tables with same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I currently have a database with two tables **tc_services** and **tc_game_services**, where these contain different information about the same service. They both are identified by the *service_id* field, where I need to pull the *billing_id* from one and *game_id* from the other.

Now I found some examples in other questions, however when ran, they just provide me a list of these two values for every service, rather than the specific one I am trying to query from.

What do I need to correct in this query?

```
SELECT
  tcservices.billing_id,
  tcgameservices.game_id
FROM tc_services AS tcservices
INNER JOIN tc_game_services AS tcgameservices ON tcservices.service_id = '1812';
```

Comment: instead of using tcservices.service_id = '1812' which should be on your WHERE clause, try using tcservices.service_id = tcgameservices.service_id

Comment: Table aliases almost as long as table names... I'd save some typing and have tcs and tcgs for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very basic SQL. You didn't specify a joining condition on those tables. As you've mentioned, your common column is `service_id`. Connect both tables using this condition, and then in `WHERE` clause put the logic on retrieval of record for a specific `service_id`.

```
SELECT
  tcservices.billing_id,
  tcgameservices.game_id
FROM tc_services AS tcservices
INNER JOIN tc_game_services AS tcgameservices ON tcservices.service_id = tcgameservices.service_id
WHERE tcservices.service_id = '1812';
```

---

**Explaining the behaviour of your approach** (the line below): you pulled every record from `tc_services` matching a criteria `service_id = '1812'` and then cross-joined it with every record from `tc_gameservices`. This is how you got your result.

```
INNER JOIN tc_game_services AS tcgameservices ON tcservices.service_id = '1812'
```

---

I would suggest cutting the length of table aliases to save some typing and make the code look neater. This might particularly come in handy when dealing with larger and complicated queries.

As a side note, if your `service_id` is of `Integer` datatype then you don't need single quotes around the value.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response, I appreciate it. I've never really used JOIN statements much and always find a workaround for that reason. This made it extremely simple and will come in very handy in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  tcservices.billing_id,
  tcgameservices.game_id
FROM tc_services AS tcservices
INNER JOIN tc_game_services AS tcgameservices ON tcservices.service_id = tcgameservices.service_id 
 where tcservices.service_id = '1812';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ON` to specify the relationhip between the two, so equality on `service_id` then filter the results with `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
  tcservices.billing_id,
  tcgameservices.game_id
FROM tc_services AS tcservices
INNER JOIN tc_game_services AS tcgameservices ON tcservices.service_id = tcgameservices.service_id
WHERE tcservices.service_id = 1812
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should but the ID you're searching for in the WHERE clause and specify the column you want to join in your INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT tcservices.billing_id, tcgameservices.game_id
FROM tc_services AS tcservices
INNER JOIN tc_game_services AS tcgameservices ON tcservices.service_id = tcgameservices.service_id
WHERE tcservices.service_id = '1812';
```